# Why can't I get curl installed in my linux?

Tags: 18.04, apt, package-management, curl

```
arbas18@arbas18-HP-245-G6-Notebook-PC:~$ sudo apt-get install curl
[sudo] password for arbas18:         
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 curl : Depends: libcurl4 (= 7.58.0-2ubuntu3.10) but it is not going to be installed
 libpam-systemd : Depends: systemd (= 237-3ubuntu10.3)
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
arbas18@arbas18-HP-245-G6-Notebook-PC:~$
```

Comment: Have you tried `apt --fix-broken install` as suggested by the response?

Comment: Check this out: https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa/142808#142808

Answer (score -2):

I would do what it says in the help(ful) message:

> sudo apt --fix-broken install

Then make sure you are up to date:

> sudo apt update
> sudo apt upgrade

And then try installing curl again

> sudo apt-get install curl